# Android - Clicking on Home button to clear activity from stack

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app, when I click on the home button, I wish to clear the activity stack if the home button is pressed. Could anyone please help me. Lets say there are 2 activities Activity A and Activity B. 
If we click the home button from Activity B, and relaunch app, I wish to launch the app from Activity A but it is resuming from Activity B. Could anyone please help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just call finish() in your Acitivity B onPause() method.

Comment: This workaround is OK but if another App (Like messaging) takes foreground the Activity B will be destroyed anyways

Comment: True, its just a "quick hint" ;) with my hopes it will guide the person to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Try Adding the tag `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in your manifest for activity A to have the launcher always go to that activity.

Answer (score 0):

Care with the accepted answer, if you rotate your device or another app takes foreground, your View will be destroyed because onPause() method will be called. If you want to destroy your activity by only tapping Home button I recommend this:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){
        finish();            
    } else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: User wants to remove **all activities** from the task, not just the current one. Your answer will only remove the top activity on the stack.